# String is a class and cannot be used as an expression

Tags: vb.net

I typed the following in Visual Studio 2010 Express, it is a sample Windows app for navigating to a URI in the web browser:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
String site = TextBox1.Text.
```

I get an Error:

> String is a class type and cannot be used as an expression visual studio 2010 express

The source can be found at

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402526(v=vs.92).aspx

Comment: Is the `.` at the end of `TextBox1.Text.` typo or real code?

Comment: Hm, originally your question was marked C#. Didn't you try to type Visual Basic code in the C# file?

Comment: I'm not at home in vb.net, but I think you can define a string like this: Dim site as String = TextBox1.Text;

Comment: You are defining a variable in a c# style rather than a visual basic style.

Comment: No, I have tried it in VB.net by using Dim site as String = TextBox1.Text . When i tried hitting the button it didn't navigate to the url.

Comment: looks like you are mixing c# with vb.net there

Comment: My project requirement is to do the whole thing in C# only . Can you please help me figure put how to do this using C#

Comment: Why didn't you ask for that in the first place?

Comment: And if it didn't navigate properly, well, we can't help, since we don't know the code used to navigate.

Comment: If you want help converting VB to C# then ask for that (or use an online converter). As it stands your question isn't actually a question.

Comment: You linked to a C# tutorial, posted some VB code, and are now asking for help converting the VB to C#? That just doesn't make sense.

Comment: You should know, you can't write a C# program with VB express. You need C# express.

Comment: Let me rephrase my question. I typed the following C# code in microsoft visual studio 2010 express for windows phone         Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    String site = TextBox1.Text                   WebBrowser1.Navigate(New Uri(site, UriKind.Absolute))   I get an error saying that String is a class type and cannot be used as an expression and in this line WebBrowser1.Navigate(New Uri(site, UriKind.Absolute)) i get an error saying 'site is not declared. It may be inaccesible due to its protection level'. Please help me out with this.

Comment: That is not C#. Please code in C# if you want help with C#.

Comment: First of all, to use C# code you need to create a C# project instead of a VB project.

Comment: Can you guys go through this link        http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402526(v=vs.92).aspx  I coded in the same way as mentioned in that. Can you please let me know why I've got the error mentioned above

Comment: @user1520740: You get the error because you are mixing in C# code in your VB code.

Comment: @user1520740 - If you coded in C#, why did you write this line:  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) ?  That is NOT c# code.  And I can't see that code anywhere on the link you posted earlier.

Answer (score 7):

You are declaring variables wrong. In VB, you declare a variable like this:

```
Dim site As String = TextBox1.Text
```

Comment: I am doing it in C# , not VB.net .When i type the following C# CODE Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) 
String site = TextBox1.Text   I get the following error with the word String marked in purple and then an error for site that says 'site is not declared, it may be inaccesible due to its protection level'                                   String is a class type and cannot be used as an expression visual studio 2010 express

Comment: That is not even reminiscent of C# code. Please read some basic C# tutorials.

Comment: The dot at the end of Textbox1.text is a typo.Sorry for that

Answer (score 5):

In VB write

```vb
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Dim site As String = TextBox1.Text
    '...
End Sub
```

In C# write

```cs
private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string site = TextBox1.Text;
    //...
}
```

You mixed both languages.

It is also a good idea to give the controls meaningful names. E.g. `siteTextBox` or `txtSite` or `tbSite`. Because, how should one know what `TextBox17` or `Button19` should stand for? If you create event handlers they will "inherit" this name, e.g. `btnOK_Click`, this tells more than `Button3_Click`.